# Full strack trace in Google Analytics V2 for Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, stack-trace

I use Google Analytics V2 for Android to do crash reporting.

I properly get crashes but I can't find where to read the full stack trace.

Is it possible to see the full stack trace when using Google analytics V2 for android ?

All I can see is the following.

[image]

Comment: I read from the FAQ :  `if your question generally covers … [...] - software tools commonly used by programmers [...]`. Isn't my question practical and answerable ? (As the FAQ states) Why is this off topic ?

Comment: See [ExceptionReporter / ExceptionParser][1]  or [my blog post][2] for more details.

[1]: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions#exception-reporter
[2]: http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-analytics-easytracker-detailed.html